# Proving Binomial using double counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was given this problem to prove in two different ways, but I am having trouble proving by the technique called Double Counting. We have to describe two counting procedures that count the same set.

$$\dbinom{2n}{2} = 2\dbinom{n}{2} + n^2$$

I am not quite sure I fully understand double counting.
I was hoping someone can advise me on how to go about this proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $2n$ different-flavoured doughnuts, $n$ in Box 1 and $n$ in Box 2. We want to choose $2$ doughnuts to have for breakfast.

There are $\binom{2n}{2}$ ways to pick these doughnuts. Let us count the number of ways to pick the doughnuts *in another way*.

We could pick $2$ doughnuts from Box 1. This can be done in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways.

We could pick them from Box 2. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to do this.

We could pick $1$ from Box 1 and $1$ from Box 2. There are $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{1}$ ways to do this. Thus
$$\binom{2n}{2}=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{1}.$$
More simply, $\binom{2n}{2}=2\binom{n}{2}+n^2$.

**Remark:** The formula even holds for $n=1$, if we use the convention that $\binom{1}{2}=0$.

Comment: Suppose that we use two different (correct!) methods to count the number of ways to carry out task $T$. Suppose that one method gives the answer $A$, in our case, $A=\binom{2n}{2}$, and another method gives answer $B$, in our case $2\binom{n}{1}+n^2$. Then we must have $A=B$.

Comment: @drhab thanks guys, so to clarify.
we have n blue shirts and n green shirts, we want to choose two shirts and that can be done $\binom{2n}{2}$. 
Then to count another way is we have $\binom{n}{2}$ to pick a blue shirt and $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to pick a green shirt and the chance where one is blue and one is green is $n^2$

Comment: Close. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to pick two blue, and $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to pick $2$ green, and $n^2$ ways to pick one of each.

Comment: Ok so just to revise my comment. @drhab thanks guys, so to clarify.
we have n blue shirts and n green shirts, we want to choose two shirts and that can be done $\binom{2n}{2}$. 
Then to count another way is we have $\binom{n}{2}$ to pick two blue shirts and $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to pick two green shirts and $n^2 $ to pick one of each

Comment: so expanding $\binom{2n}{2}$ is this $\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{1}.$?

Comment: Yes, that gives an *algebraic* proof, and you were asked to give a combinatorial argument. Expanding the left side gives after some simplification $n(2n-1)$. Expanding the right side gives $2\cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n^2$, which simplifies to $(n)(n-1)+n^2$ and then to $2n^2-n=n(2n-1)$.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out why $\frac{2n!}{(2n-2)!2!} = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}$

Comment: We have $(2n)!=(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)!$. The $(2n-2)!$ cancels with the $(2n-2)!$ at the bottom.

Comment: ok I see you expand the numerator so you can cancel

Comment: That's right. The same idea shows that $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{(n)(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$. So for example $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The most natural thing that $\binom{2n}2$ counts is subsets $\{a,b\}$ of two distinct elements of a $2n$-element set; since each pair is counted only once, one may assume $a<b$. This can be interpreted as the index $(a,b)$ of a single entry above the diagonal in a $2n\times2n$ matrix. Now can you decompose that set of positions into three parts, counting respectively $\binom n2$, $\binom n2$, and $n^2$ elements?

Answer (score 3):

Let there be $n$ black marbles and $n$ white marbles. Then $2$ marbles are picked out. That can be done (not minding the color) in $\binom{2n}{2}$ ways. Another way is to look at the possibilities where both are black: $\binom{n}2$ ways, the possibilities where both are white: $\binom{n}2$ ways, and the possibilities where one is black and one is white: $n^2$ ways. So in together $2\binom{n}2+n^2$ ways.

Comment: so expanding $\binom{2n}{2}$ is this $\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{1}.$?